# Django: How to create a mixin to set common attributes for every model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-class-based-views

I have a model mixin that sets `created_at`, `created_by`, `updated_at` and `updated_by` which I then inherit to most of the models in my project. This model mixin works fine. Obviously setting `created_at` and `modified_at` is very easy due to `auto_now_add` and `auto_now`.

```
class Timestampable(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        db_index=True,
        verbose_name=_('created at')
    )
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, related_name="created%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        db_index=True,
        verbose_name=_('updated at')
    )
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, related_name="updated%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

But, what I want is to also create a mixin (or maybe subclass) `CreateView` and `UpdateView` to set `created_by` and `updated_by` to be `self.request.user` everywhere those CBVs are used ( I would guess by modifying `get_form()` or `form_valid()`). I'll also need to create a similar admin mixin to modify `save_model()`.

I have never created a custom mixin and the things I have found/tried aren't working. For example I got subclassing CreateView working by modifying `get_form()` but then, I couldn't further modify `get_form()` in the various `class ModelXCreate(...)` views I created.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this? It'd be super useful to be able to have such a mixin and keep things DRY.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `form_valid` method and thus work with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class CreateUpdateMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.instance
        if instance.pk is None:  # created
            instance.created_by = instance.updated_by = self.request.user
        else:  # updated
            instance.updated_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Then we can use this mixin for our `CreateView`/`UpdateView`:

```
class MyCreateView(CreateUpdateMixin, CreateView):
    # …
    pass

class MyUpdateView(CreateUpdateMixin, UpdateView):
    # …
    pass
```

Comment: Hi thanks very much for this. That's actually what I already tried, but in the get_form() of MyCreateView (where you've got pass), the subsequent changes weren't taking effect. I.e. it wasn't inheriting properly and being further modified. Would you be able to edit your answer to include how to inherit and further modify form_valid() please?

Comment: @David: exactly what did you define in `get_form()`? Normally you should only override `form_valid`. Note that you need to specify the `CreateUpdateMixin` *before* the `CreateView` as parent class. The order of parents *matters* when determining the MRO.